# Handlebars templating forms / req.body gives same (first) {{id}} for multiple same <form> of template after post

Tags: html, forms, express, post, handlebars.js

I currently work on making a page that will render rows of DB with handlebars. Where the client can approve or decline for only one row of render. Huh.

This is handlebars template that renders a page on load, only `<form>` section is important here:

```
   <h1>Svi poslovi</h1>
 <section id="admin" class="container">

   {{#gigs}}

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{company_name}}</td>
    <td>{{activity}}</td>
    <td>{{byuser}}</td>
    <td>{{byemail}}</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="{{id}}" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" id="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" id="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>
   {{else}}
   <p>Trenutno nema poslova na listi.</p>
{{/gigs}}

 </section>
```

That works wonderful in browser I get this output:

```
<section id="admin" class="container">


   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2222222222222                                                                                       </td>
    <td>Informatika - Software                                                                              </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="97" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2222222222222222222222                                                                              </td>
    <td>IT                                                                                                  </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="98" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2222222222222222222222222222222                                                                     </td>
    <td>IT                                                                                                  </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="99" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2222222222222222                                                                                    </td>
    <td>Konsalting                                                                                          </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="100" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2222                                                                                                </td>
    <td>IT                                                                                                  </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="101" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22222222                                                                                            </td>
    <td>Elektrotehnika - Mašinstvo                                                                          </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="102" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>222222222222222                                                                                     </td>
    <td>Komercijala - Prodaja                                                                               </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="103" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22222222222                                                                                         </td>
    <td>Komercijala - Prodaja                                                                               </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="104" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22222222222                                                                                         </td>
    <td>Komercijala - Prodaja                                                                               </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="105" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22222                                                                                               </td>
    <td>IT                                                                                                  </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="106" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>222222                                                                                              </td>
    <td>IT                                                                                                  </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="107" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22222222222                                                                                         </td>
    <td>Građevinarstvo                                                                                      </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="108" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ewwewe                                                                                              </td>
    <td>Komercijala - Prodaja                                                                               </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="109" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>nemojme                                                                                             </td>
    <td>Konsalting                                                                                          </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="110" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2222222222222                                                                                       </td>
    <td>Konsalting                                                                                          </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="111" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Merkator Doo                                                                                        </td>
    <td>IT                                                                                                  </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="112" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22222222                                                                                            </td>
    <td>it                                                                                                  </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="113" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>222222222222222                                                                                     </td>
    <td>Grafička industrija                                                                                 </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="114" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2222222222                                                                                          </td>
    <td>Grafički dizajn                                                                                     </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="115" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="gig">
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Kompanija</th>
    <th>Kategorija</th>
    <th>Vlasnik oglasa</th>
    <th>Kontakt email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>222222222222                                                                                        </td>
    <td>Grafički dizajn                                                                                     </td>
    <td>222222222                                                                                           </td>
    <td>pm2@pm.pm                                                                                                                                                                                               </td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
<form action="/admin/isposted" method="post">
    <input name="idposla" value="116" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div class="ujmjaoca">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="posted" value="1" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Objavljeno</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="posted" value="0" type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">Neobjavljeno</label>
    </div>
</form>


     <div class="activity">

     </div>
   </div>

 </section>
```

Problem is that when I press button form being posted I get in console output: `{ idposla: '97', posted: '1' }` , no matters if I press first form or last form `idposla:` will always be `'97`, I wants it to be same as `idposla:` where I press button but its only picks first `{{id}}`..

This is par of code in expressjs:

- get:

```
router.get('/', isloggedin, (req, res) =>
    Gig.findAll()
        .then(gigs => {
            res.render('admin', {gigs, layout: 'main'})
                        }
             )
          );

function isloggedin(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        if(req.user.whoami != 3){
            res.redirect('/settings')}
            else {
                next();
            }}
    else{
        res.redirect('/users/login');
    }

}
```

- post:

```
router.post('/isposted', isloggedin, (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);})
```

Later I will add more code on expressjs part of code, this is just a test to get valid output..

Please help me with this I didn't make next step last few days.. Thanks, regards!

Comment: What did you expected `object` send to your backend? **Like this:** `{ idposla: '97', posted: '1' }` or this: `{ posted: '1' }. I need to know what the object looks like you expected.

Comment: Like your first example, I would later use something like `let {idposla, posted} = req.body;` in expressjs route.post part of code

Answer (score 0):

**To handle this form request**, you can add new route like as this code below :

```js
app.post('/admin/isposted', (req, res) => {
  // do some stuff here...
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send(req.body);
})
```

‍ Now you can **try again** and you will get `result` as you expected .

**For example:** you can follow this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-currying-qc7we

I hope it's can help you .

Comment: pardon, I was pasted wrong part of js code.. I'm very sorry! I have done that before, and thanks for taking time to help me, problem is not here..